# Unable to run qgis_process from command line for native:atlaslayouttopdf QGIS algorithm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, command-line

I've tried to run below commands in my terminal

1st try

```
qgis_process run native:atlaslayouttopdf --project=/home/thomasg/own-projects/sample-qgis-server/projects/atlas_minimum.qgs --LAYOUT=v1_layout_atlas --OUTPUT=/tmp/atlas1.pdf
```

2nd try

```
qgis_process run native:atlaslayouttopdf --project=/home/thomasg/own-projects/sample-qgis-server/projects/atlas_minimum.qgs --LAYOUT=v1_layout_atlas --COVERAGE_LAYER=/home/thomasg/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp --OUTPUT=/tmp/atlas1.pdf
```

In both cases, it complains about

```
----------------
Inputs
----------------

COVERAGE_LAYER: /home/thomasg/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp
LAYOUT: v1_layout_atlas
OUTPUT: /tmp/atlas1.pdf
project:    /home/thomasg/own-projects/sample-qgis-server/projects/atlas_minimum.qgs


Cannot find layout with name "v1_layout_atlas"
ERROR:  Cannot find layout with name "v1_layout_atlas"
```

I've tested with and without specifying COVERAGE_LAYER as I was not sure if it was mandatory.

The problem is that the atlas layout name exists and has been activated to support atlas. I'm able to run manually the same processing algorithm within my QGIS project with the same layout and with QGIS Python console.

Does someone has any clue about the issue? Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Related issue on the QGIS tracker due to feedback from a QGIS core dev on Twitter https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43823 Need to wait to make an answer it seems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a typo in your command: `--project=...` should be `--project_path=...`